# make utility (or make file) giving unexpected output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying a simple echo in make file as follows

```
@echo "7463"
```

It gives following output (quotations are printed as well)

```
"7643"
```

My expected output was 7643 (without quotations)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are those the exact quotes you used in the file? Not smart quotes by accident? What does the rest of the makefile look like? What version of make specifically?

Comment: Are you trying to get 7643 without quotes, or understand what happened?

Comment: You might also want to check which shell make is using.   Run `echo $$0` from a make recipe to find out.  Also try cutting and pasting the command (without the @), to a shell prompt, and see what's printing.  It may not be regular quotes like Etan suggested.

Comment: In addition to the version of make, which should ALWAYS provide, you should specify what operating system you're using and what version of the operating system.